# Accessing Ubuntu Local Server from browser in Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, vagrant, macos-sierra

So I set up a Linux virtual machine following Vagrant's 'getting started' documentation - it's running Ubuntu Precise. Everything else is working fine, but I am not able to access it through the browser from my host machine (my Macbook). Ultimately, I want to run RStudio Server from the VM, so it's important this works.

I have set up port forwarding on my Mac although I'm not sure if it's configured correctly. To explain in more detail:

1 - I've got my pfctl config file sitting in the /etc/ folder. It looks like this

```
# /etc/pf-vagrant.conf
# sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf-vagrant.conf

rdr-anchor "forwarding"
load anchor "forwarding" from "/etc/pf.anchors/vagrant.apache.forwarding"
```

2 - I've got the anchor file sitting in the /etc/pf.anchors folder

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
```

3 - When I test the validity of my anchor file, everything seems good

```
$ sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/vagrant.apache.forwarding
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
```

4 - Then when I execute the pfctl command from the terminal I receive the following error:

```
sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf-vagrant.conf

pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
/etc/pf-vagrant.conf:5: syntax error
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

5 - Terminal shows connection refused when I type

```
$ nc -v 127.0.0.1 80    
nc: connectx to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

6 - When I do the same after ssh'ing into Ubuntu I get

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ nc -v 90.254.170.192 80    
Connection to <MY IP ADDRESS> 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

7 - I've tried allowed connections from my host machine using variations of the following command.

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm slowly losing my mind trying to get this to work.

UPDATE #1 - My Vagrantfile

Sure, here it is. Thanks for helping.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  config.vm.network "public_network"  
end
```

Comment: can you show the Vagrantfile, if you have the file correctly setup you dont need all this update in your VM

Comment: Sure, here it is. Thanks for helping. I've appended the code to the main question.

Comment: after you run `vagrant up` can you just try to point your browser to `localhost:8080`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri when I point the browser to localhost:8080 Chrome gives me the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error message. When I type `curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'` into Terminal it tells me `url: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused`.